# Generic way to convert number words to numbers (e.g. "first" to "1st")

Tags: javascript

i want a  generic  method  using  javascript to  convert

the values like first floor, second floor, ground floor will be converted to below format,

> Ground Floor: Gr. Floor
>   First Floor: 1st Floor
>   Twenty floor: 20th Floor

right now  i am  using  following code
but that not the   correct way as i cannot  write for all the floors (50th floor,90th floor) so please   help me  with this

```
function validpress(iKeyascii)   
 {
if( iKeyascii=='77'||iKeyascii=='76'||iKeyascii=='68'||iKeyascii=='73'||iKeyascii=='88'||iKeyascii=='86'||iKeyascii=='67')
{
alert("Roman numbers are not allowed.");    
return false;
}   
var txt= document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
//document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = txt.toUpperCase();
 var patternforGFloor = new RegExp('\\b[G|g][R|r][O|o][U|u][n|N][D|d]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');
var patternfor1Floor = new RegExp('\\b[F|f][I|i][R|r][S|s][T|t]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');
var patternfor2Floor = new RegExp('\\b[S|s][E|e][C|c][O|o][N|n][D|d]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');

var patternfor3Floor = new RegExp('\\b[T|t][H|h][I|i][R|r][D|d]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');
var patternfor4Floor = new RegExp('\\b[F|f][O|o][U|u][R|r][T|t][H|h]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');
var patternfor5Floor = new RegExp('\\b[F|f][I|i][F|f][T|t][H|h]*\\.*\\s*[F|f][L|l][O|o][O|o][R|r]\\b');


     if (txt.match(patternforGFloor) )
     {
     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace(patternforGFloor,"Gr.Floor");
     }

      if (txt.match(patternfor1Floor))
     {

     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace(patternfor1Floor,"1st. Floor");
     }

     if (txt.match(patternfor2Floor) )
     {
     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace(patternfor2Floor,"2nd.Floor");
     }

      if (txt.match(patternfor3Floor))
     {

     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace(patternfor3Floor,"3rd. Floor");
     }
  if (txt.match( patternfor4Floor))
     {

     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace( patternfor4Floor,"4th. Floor");
     }

if (txt.match( patternfor5Floor))
     {

     document.getElementById ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value=txt.replace( patternfor5Floor,"5th. Floor");
     }

 }
```

Comment: This is some terrible terrible code, but especially because of that I think it's a valid question. No need to downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your Regexen are madness. Use the **case-insensitive** flag `/i` and use Regex literals so you don't have to escape everything twice:

```
var patternfor1Floor = /\bfirst\s*floor\b/i;
```

Second, you'll want find the patterns in the English language and reuse them:

```
first, twenty-first, one-hundred-twenty-first
second, twenty-second, one-hundred-twenty-second
```

The "first" and "second" parts are repetitive, so you only need to define `first` through `ninth` and their values once. The same goes for `twenty`, `thirty` and `hundred`, `thousand` etc. So you can break down a number like `one-hundred-twenty-first` into "(one) hundred", "twenty" and "first" and add the values. "eleven" through "nineteen" are exceptions you'll need to recognize separately.

Adding a `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` to the end of the number is trivial by looking at its last digit.

I can't and won't give you a complete solution here, try to get somewhere with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what number is meant by a string of words, 
and return the number with the correct ordinal suffix.

This will work up to 999 floors, if your users are good spellers (or they use numbers instead of words).

Don't run long calculations on keypresses- do them when the user finishes typing, onchange or onblur.

```
Run=window.Run || {};

Number.prototype.nth= function(){
    if(this> 3 && this<21) return this+'th';
    var suffix= this%10;
    switch(suffix){
        case 1:return this+'st';
        case 2:return this+'nd';
        case 3:return this+'rd';
        default:return this+'th';
    }
}
Run.makeFloors= function(){
    var nums= [
        ['ground', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
        'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'],
        ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety', 'hundred']
    ],
    floor={
        first:1, second:2, third:3, fifth:5, eighth:8, ninth:9, twelfth:12
    };
    nums[0].forEach(function(itm, i){
        floor[itm]= i;
        if(itm>3)floor[itm+'th']= i;
    });
    nums[1].forEach(function(itm, i){
        if(itm) floor[itm]= 10*i;
        floor[itm+'th']= i;
        if(itm<100) floor[itm.slice(0, -2)+'tieth']= i;
    });
    return floor;
}
Run.getFloor= function(s){
    Run.floor= Run.floor || Run.makeFloors();
    if(parseInt(s)) return parseInt(s).nth()+' Floor';
    s= s.toLowerCase().replace(/(\W+|and|floor)/g, '').replace(/y(\S)/, 'y $1');
    var F= 0, nums, ax, s2;
    var ax= s.indexOf('hundred');
    if(ax!= -1){
        s= s.split(/hundred/);
        s2= s[0]? floor[s[0]]:1;
        F= 100*s2;
        s= s[1];
    }
    if(floor[s]) F+= floor[s];
    else{
        s= s.split(/ +/);
        if(floor[s[0]]) F+= floor[s[0]];
        if(floor[s[1]]) F+= floor[s[1]];
    }
    if(F== 0) return 'Gr. Floor';
    return F.nth()+' Floor';
}

Run.getFloor('Fourth')= 4th Floor
Run.getFloor('twenty second')= 22nd Floor
Run.getFloor('eighty-fifth')= 85th Floor
Run.getFloor('ground')= Gr.Floor
Run.getFloor('Twelve')= 12th Floor
Run.getFloor(21)= 21st Floor
Run.getFloor('one hundred and seven')= 107th Floor
Run.getFloor('nine hundred and ninety nine')= 999th Floor


//to support old browsers you need to shim Array.forEach

Array.prototype.forEach= [].forEach || function(fun, scope){
    var T= this, L= T.length, i= 0;
    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
        while(i< L){
            if(i in T){
                fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return T;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a Javascript HASHTable.

```
var myHash = new Hashtable();

myHash.put("First Floor", "1st");
myHash.put("Second Floor", "2nd");


alert( myHash.get('First Floor') ); // "1st"
```

You can get this JS function from [here.](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/)

[This link might also be helpful.](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html)

**Edit:**

Drawback of this approach is that you cannot handle upper/lower cases.
But you can add all the keys in your HashTable in lower case and also convert your input key to lower case in order to get the right value. Cheers !