# Text into number convesion

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

Hmm Iv tried but they do not seem to work unless im going wrong somewhere in explaining it. I appreciate the fast responses!

Let me try again with a different (better example)

age can be entered as numbers. Now sex the user is only going to enter male or female. So male=200 and female=100

These need to be converted before they can be used as a value 2

```
function add() {
```

So i do need to convert them to figures to run the formula. Sorry if I have not explained well.

Comment: If your question is "is it possible", then the answer is yes.

Comment: Input with the type `number`, and you're asking for letters ?

Comment: This is pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802286/generic-way-to-convert-number-words-to-numbers-e-g-first-to-1st

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Words to numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want to convert `"8"` to `8`:

```
var age = +$("#age").val();
```

This will convert the value in `#age` to a number. You don't need jQuery to do the conversion, but you can use jQuery's `.val()` for taking the value out of `<input>`.

---

#### If you want to convert `"eight"` to `8`:

First of all, change the type from `number` to `text`.

If you want to convert a number written in English to a number, you can use an `Object`.

```
var nums = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    ...
};
var age = nums[$("#age").val().toLowerCase()];
```

However this is greatly not recommended because you will have to create an entry for every number you accept.

A better approach would be separating the ones and the tens so on and so forth, but you will have to deal with special cases such as `"eleven", "fifty"` and invalid inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014376/283863

---

#### Fun fact

Interestingly, it is [possible to do the other way around](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) (Number to Word) in modern browsers:

```
var number = 10;
number.toLocaleString("zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec");  //it supports many languages,
                                                   //including Chinese.
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to convert a string into an integer. "eight" -> 8

Comment: @DACrosby - But it clearly says the input type is `number` so it is not possible for users to enter "eight"...

Comment: The post also states " say I enter 'eight'. Is it possible to convert that 'eight' into a number?". I see your point though, this post has a couple issues going on.

Comment: @DACrosby - I added both possibilities so he can choose what he wants ;)

Comment: Good call. Maybe mention the input type issue as well since `type="number"` is not `type="text"`

Comment: @DACrosby - I added that and also an "interesting fact".

Answer (score 0):

Use a map

```
var numbers = {
    'one'   : 1,
    'two'   : 2,
    'three' : 3,
    'four'  : 4,
    ... etc
}

var age = numbers[ $('#ageinletter').val() ];
```

with a text input

Answer (score 0):

Use the Number() function.

```
var age = Number($('#age').val());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

This is only for "1" => 1, not "one" => 1. I'm not sure if there is an out-of-the-box way to convert from text to numbers.